# Azure DevOps CI/CD pipelines for ADLS Gen2 resource

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-data-lake, azure-data-lake-gen2

I am working on creating CI/CD pipelines for all resources like ADF, DataBricks and ADLS Gen2.

I have completed CI/CD on ADF and Databricks, but couldn't see a way to implement CI/CD on ADLS resource.

1. Is there any way to implement azure devops CI/CD pipeline on ADLS
   gen2 resource?
2. If direct methods are not possible, once our files
   that has to be stored in ADLS is available at a github repository, Is there any way to deploy/copy those files to an ADLS resource?

I didn't see any documentation/article regarding CI/CD on ADLS, so seeking help here!

Any leads much appreciated!

Comment: Do you mean provisioning / ensuring the storage account in an environment? Or copying seed files into the blob store?

Comment: Either ways, I do have separate blob storages for different environment, but the reservoirs and folder structures are same.
If there is no option to link an adls gen2 storage resource with Git, then copying files into the adls from devops pipeline will help.

Comment: Assuming your DevOps pipeline has already checked out your git repo, there's a copy task. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/deploy/azure-file-copy?view=azure-devops

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I know, there is no way to integrate a blob resource to github repository directly, but you could add the files in git repository and then can do a AzureBlob file copy activity to copy these files into a reservoir as shown below.

Provide container name and master folder location(blob prefix) and copy the files.
If there not exists a reservoir, this task will try to create a new with provided name.

[image]